# RegEx Lowercase Letters and Hyphen

Tags: regex

Can someone help me write a regex that matches only all lower case letters plus hyphens.

Example: this-page-name

Comment: @Tomalak will do in the future, sorry about that. [a-z\-]+ is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will catch 1 or more characters that are either lowercase a-z or the hyphen

```
[a-z\-]+
```

The trick is to escape the hyphen with a backslash.

For completeness, you can add an appropriate boundary such as \b on each end to signify a full word match, or ^ and $ to make it match a full line.

Comment: what about regex for all letter cases and a hyphen?

Comment: A late reply for @Devops-Paddy.  To capture both cases, you can use [a-zA-Z\-]+

Answer (score 33):

Mike Clark's pattern `[a-z\-]+`  would match `-start-dash-double-dash---and-end-dash-`

Maybe `^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$` is little bit more precise.

Comment: Based on the example OP provided, this answer is better IMO

Comment: Better use `^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/vcHI7I/1)) if regex engine supports non-capturing groups (all non-POSIX regex flavors basically). The anchors are not necessary in C++ `regex_match`, Java's `.matches()`, Python's `re.fullmatch`, as usual.